# Inine CSS for Text inside DIV

Tags: javascript, css

Inside the DIV Tag

```
<div name="layer1" style="background-color:lightblue;">
<hr>Site:Downtown DataCenter Device: 2KBS</hr>
</div>
```

Hi ,

I am using Inline CSS Styling .
Inside the hr tag of my Div tag i want to have the text "site" and "Device" as bold and with big font ?

How can i have it

Please advice .

Comment: <hr/> is not meant to contain content.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, `<hr>` is not intended to contain anything, much like `<img>` or `<br />`.

Try this:

```
<div class="layer1">
    <strong>Site:</strong> Downtown DataCenter <strong>Device:</strong> 2KBS
</div>
<hr></hr>
```

The CSS might look like this:

```
.layer1
{
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.layer1 strong
{
    font-size: larger;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try putting your content in a `p`. `hr` is a horizontal rule which is an empty element [w3c specifcation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element). Put the text that you want into `span` elements and then apply styling `font-weight:bold;font-size:20px` or whatever size you want.